# One Apache virtual host resolves to index of/, while the others resolve correctly

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost

I'm having an issues trying to resolve a third virtual host. The third virtual host always resolves to index of/.

Localhost and eshop.lh both correctly resolve their own individual index files.

**UPDATE 1** I've added another test vHost, this also does not resolve correctly and serves index of/. Removing eshop and localhost does not change this behaviour.

**UPDATE 2**
Changed loglevel config to debug.

The errors i'm getting is no matching ServerName but it seems to be looking in SSL 433 VHost configurations. The names and paths are correct, no typos.

```
[ssl:debug] [pid 14388:tid 1924] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2364): [client 127.0.0.1:54023] AH02044: No matching SSL virtual host for servername engine.lh found (using default/first virtual host)
```

It then defaults the connection to (server www.example.com:443) which is the first configures (default) SSL VHost in the httpd-ssl.conf file.

As a test, i spoofed the ServerName for eshop.lh to see if it would also serve me the SSL Vhost default, but it doesn't. It serves me localhost which is the first Vhost configuration for port 80.

Vhost configuration: Showing spoofed eshop.lh and including 433 config too, that i left out previously.

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:46)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:46)
         port 80 namevhost engine.lh (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:53)
         port 80 namevhost test.lh (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:60)
         port 80 namevhost eshot.lh (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:67)
*:443                  www.example.com (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:121)
```

**UPDATE 3**
Re-installed xampp and it appears to be working smoothly now.

**My configuration:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop.lh/"
    ServerName eshop.lh
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/engine.lh/"
    ServerName engine.lh
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 eshop.lh
127.0.0.1 engine.lh
```

The paths are correct on my machine.

It's engine.lh that won't resolve correctly. eshop.lh works fine.

The file inside the engine.lh directory are simply:

read.me
index.html

Calling httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS produces:

```
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:44)
         port 80 namevhost eshop.lh (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:52)
         port 80 namevhost engine.lh (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:60)
```

I restart apache with: hpptd -k restart or via the control panel.

In the apache docs: Name-based Virtual Host support, it gives this example to serve up different vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot "/www/domain"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So...  `http://localhost/` is fine, you get the file from `C:/xampp/htdocs/localhost`.  `http://eshop.lh` you get the file from `C:/xampp/htdocs/eshop.lh/`.  What do you get with `http://engine.lh` ?  Note, if you ask for `http://127.0.0.1` you will get the first VirtualHost.  When Apache does not find a match, it returns the files from the first VirtualHost if finds.  FYI: "nothing works" is not a question, explain in detail what you are getting.

Comment: @Nic3500 Sorry, bad wording on my part, i over looked localhost when writing the problem description. Localhost resolves it's own index.html correctly, as does eshop.lh. only engine.lh resolves to index of/ . I also added another test Vhost after engine.lh, this also only resolves to index of/.

Comment: Put `LogLevel debug` and separate your log files for each `VirtualHost`.  You should do that anyway, combining the logs is hard to debug.  You would then  have 3 CustomLog and 3 error logs.  Then check for typos.  `engine.lh`.  Is that `l` as in lima or something else?  In some fonts, `l L 1` are almost the same.  Then test with only your `engine.lh` VirtualHost.  Comment all the others.  There is nothing wrong with what you pasted here.

Comment: oh, and what does `index of/` mean?  It shows the files from `/` ?  It shows the files from `C:/xampp/htdocs/` ?

Comment: @Nic3500 Index of/ it's showing the directory contents of xampp/htdocs DocumentRoot. I found something interesting and edited my post with an update and details (UPDATE 2). It's serverName not finding a match, but it seems to be looking in the SSL 433 vhost config and not 80. I tested spoofing the ehop.lh server name, it acts accordingly and resolves to localhost (first 80 vhost config)

Comment: Don't mix questions.  I have no clue why you are talking of SSL and port 443, your configuration only uses port 80.  Have you tried every VirtualHost one by one to ensure they are ok before mixing them?

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, the configuration uses port 80. I'm aware of that. That's the error it gives using the port 80 configuration. Think i'll reinstall and  try again. Thanks for your help.